# Ajax callback pop up window

Tags: ajax, popup, call, back

I have an Ajax callback function, which will load a html file and pop up the content of this HTMl file in a pop up window.

It works so far, however, i want to get rid of the location bar in the pop up window. 
Here is my code

> function _checkPopUpUpdate() {
>       var callback=new Object();
>       callback.success=this.onExternalSuccess;
>       callback.failure=this.onExternalFailure;
>       YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET','/ci/ajaxCustom/ajaxCheckPopupUpdate',callback);
>   };

function onExternalSuccess (o){

> ```
> if(o.responseText!==undefined)
> {
>     var str=o.responseText;
>     //document.getElementById('updateContent').innerHTML=str;
>       if(str !== 'no update') // Then pop up.
>       {
>       L=screen.width-200;
>       T=screen.height;
>       **popup=window.open(str,"","alwaysRaised=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,directories=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,height=80,width=210,left="+L+",top="+T);**
>       for (i=0;i<200;i++)
>       {
>          T=T-1;
>           popup.moveTo(L,T);
>       }
>     }
> } };
> ```
>
> function onExternalFailure (o) {
>       alert("fail"); };

So, i have the location = 0, which i think it should correct. But i still get the location bar in my pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't let you remove it. Some browsers have a setting that will disable removing it. Theres no reliable way to remove the location bar. You can test various browsers here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html